# Core Data: NSPredicate with managed objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am creating an iOS 5 app using Core Data.

I have two entities `Item` and `Category` there is a many-to-many relationship between these two entities, i.e. an `Item` belongs to many categories and a `Category` has many items.

What I am trying to do is, given a category, I want to know all the categories the items of that category is associated with. For that I am trying to execute the following request:

```
NSEntityDescription *catEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = catEntity;
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"items IN %@",[category.items allObjects]];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];    
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *categories = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

But when executing this I get the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (items IN {<Item: 0x89b9c50> (entity: Item; id: 0x89be960 <x-coredata://A5DE0832-95F1-460C-9F40-202A10E16BDC/Item/p17> ; data: {
    attributes =     (
    );
    categories =     (
        "0x89be540 <x-coredata://A5DE0832-95F1-460C-9F40-202A10E16BDC/Category/p28>",
        "0x89be680 <x-coredata://A5DE0832-95F1-460C-9F40-202A10E16BDC/Category/p29>"
    );
    name = "Some Item";
})})'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I'm not sure but it might work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY items IN %@", [category.items allObjects]];
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I did not know that the `ANY` was required,

Comment: It's because it's a to-many relationship. Either `ANY` or `ALL` need to come before the `IN`

Comment: How i can use above predicate with Not ?

Comment: @wod I think either `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (ANY items IN %@)", [category.items allObjects]]` or `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE items IN %@", [category.items allObjects]]`